# Effect of SharePoint List Throttling on SSIS Sharepoint List Source

Tags: list-view

We have a sharepoint list with 60000 rows in **All Items** view. And Admins are about to set a throttle limit of 5000 items.

Also, we have a SSIS package which gets data from above list, but from a different view - **Modified View**, which has around 500-1000 items.

What could be tha impact of list throttling of the SSIS package? Because i think there wont be any affect as number of items is less than 5000 in **Modified View** view.

Answer (score 0):

There is a User Threshold and a seperate Admin Threshold. You can set different values for each, so the SSIS can run under an admin context plus you can also schedule the SSIS to run in a window of opportunity where the Threshold limits are not applied. All settings through the admin site.